# Is it possible to use a USB guitar interface meant for ASIO on Windows with Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, drivers, usb, interface

I have the peavey xport usb guitar interface. It comes with an installation CD to set it up with ASIO drivers on windows. Would it be possible to use the interface on ubuntu so that I could make use of programs such as rakarrack?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the manual for the Peavey device led me to the CoreAudio protocol, then google led me to what seems to be a [Very Good Answer](http://createdigitalmusic.com/2009/08/linux-music-workflow-switching-from-mac-os-x-to-ubuntu-with-kim-cascone/)!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.